# google play and tablet support

Tags: java, android, google-play, tablet

Hello i am trying to publish an app to google play, but for some reason tablets can't download it. After some research i found that we must specify some uses-feature on the manifest file. can you help me know which those are?
Here's a sample of the manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Comment: probably because of this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>`

Comment: what should i use? this one:
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" 
    android:required="false"></uses-feature>

Comment: yes, if you tablet does not have sms capabilities then it not be able to download it

Comment: ok i'll upload and tomorrow will give you some feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed was this

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"></uses-feature>
```

and this:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"/>
   <supports-screens android:normalScreens="true"/>
   <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"/>
   <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```